# How to connect Cassandra database with Chicago Boss Application?

Tags: cassandra, chicagoboss, erlangweb

My cassandra database is on a VMware server. The problem is that I don't find any database adapter which can help me in connecting my cassandra database with my chicago boss(a web framework in Erlang) application. I tried [Cqerl on GitHub](https://github.com/matehat/cqerl) but I am not able to use it. Can anyone tell me the procedure for connecting cassandra with chicago boss. Any proper documentation will be a great help. Thank you.